# Reading jpeg dimensions from boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am pretty new to c++ programming and i am trying to use the above function in order to retrieve the width and the height of an image. The code of the function is:

```
 inline point2<std::ptrdiff_t> jpeg_read_dimensions(const std::string& filename) {
return jpeg_read_dimensions(filename.c_str());
 }
```

So i understand that i must send a string like:

```
string data2 = "images.jpg";
```

But i can't really get how to read what comes back from the function.

Answer (score 0):

From the [GIL reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/gil/doc/html/g_i_l_0060.html), `boost::gil::point2<T>` define:

> 2D point both axes of which have the same dimension type

You can access the properties `x` and `y`, which correspond to the width and height of the image.

Comment: Yes, i have understood that the point of the function is to get the x and y. What i have as question is how to handle the data(in which kind of variable to store them without getting error).

Comment: The function returns a `point2<std::ptrdiff_t>`, so it's the type you should use :) `point2` is defined in the namespace `boost::gil`